# How can I use pst-circ package to draw this circuit?

Tags: pstricks, pst-circ

[image: draw multiplexer with pst-circ package]
draw multiplexer with pst-circ package

Comment: What a pity.. I'm able only with circuitikz. Anyway, what did you try so far? It is always better to show some efforts in form of [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/13304).

Comment: @  Claudio Fiandrino.I can't draw with circuitikz.

Comment: No problems :) There are PSTricks experts here that will help you.. of course providing them a minimal working example would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a starter for your image:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-2)(5,6)
\logicic[nicpins=16,
  pintl=false,pintc=false,pintr=false,
  pinbl=true,pinbllabel=$S_2$,pinbc=true,pinbclabel=$S_1$,pinbr=true,pinbrlabel=$S_0$,
  pinalabel=$I_0$,pinblabel=$I_1$,pinclabel=$I_2$,pindlabel=$I_3$,
  pinelabel=$I_4$,pinflabel=$I_5$,pinglabel=$I_6$,pinhlabel=$I_7$,
  pini=false,pinj=false,pink=false,pinl=false,pinn=false,pino=false,pinp=false,
  pinmlabel=$Z$](0,0){}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and what with MUX 16x1? the MUX 16x1 has 4 S_0, S_1, S_2 and S_3 not only 3 S_0, S_1, S_2